Does a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ always have a point outside a family of 2-dimensional surfaces?
Let $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth function in both arguments. For $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, define
$$ S_a = \{\sigma(x, a) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^2\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3. $$
Does there exist a finite subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $X$ has a non-empty intersection with the complement of $S_a$, i.e., $X \cap (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S_a) \neq \emptyset$?
My conjecture is that this statement is true. I have considered some special cases as examples. For instance, if $S_a$ is the collection of 2-dimensional affine subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then it is possible to choose a finite set $X$ such that for any affine subspace $S_a$, there is always at least one point in $X$ outside $S_a$.

In my original description, $\sigma$ is a continuous function. As a comment below pointed out, a construction similar to Peano curve can fill the space. So I changed the description and required $\sigma$ be smooth.

Do you know about Peano curve?

Thank you @MoisheKohan I see your point. Let me edit the description.

More generally (I am working in the $C^1$-smooth category), suppose that $A$ is a manifold of dimension $p$, $M, N$ are (nonempty) manifolds of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively, where $m< n$. Suppose that $F: M\times A\to N$ is a ($C^1$-smooth) map; set $f_a:= F(\cdot, a)$, $a\in A$. Then there is a finite subset $B\subset N$ such that for every $a\in A$, $B\setminus f_a(M)\ne \emptyset$. More precisely, we can take $B$ consisting of (at most)
$k> p/(n-m)$ points.
To prove this, for a manifold $X$ define its $k$-fold configuration space $C_k(X)$ as the quotient of the $k$-fold product of $X$ (denoted $X^k$) by the action of the permutation group $Sym_k$. The space $C_k(X)$ is not quite a manifold, but it is a "stratified manifold." (You can safely ignore this bit of information.) Elements of $C_k(X)$ are unordered $k$-tuples $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ of points in $X$, i.e. are exactly the nonempty subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\le k$. [I am a bit sloppy here with my notation: Each finite set of cardinality $c\le k$ corresponds to $S(k,c)$ unordered $k$-tuples, where $S(k,c)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.]
Every  map $f: M\to N$ induces a map of configuration spaces,
$$
C_kf: C_k(M)\to C_k(N)
$$
as the projection of the $k$-fold product map $(f,...,f): M^k\to N^k$. Accordingly, given maps $f_a$ as above, we obtain maps $C_k f_a: C_k(M)\to C_k(N)$ and
the map
$$
C_kF: C_k(M)\times A \to C_k(N), C_kF(x,a)= C_kf_a(x), x\in C_k(M).  
$$
The map $C_kF$ is the projection of a smooth map $G_k: M^k\times A\to N$. Assuming $k> p/(n-m)$, we get that $\dim  M^k\times A < \dim N^k$. In particular, the map $G_k$ cannot be surjective, more precisely, its image has measure zero. Hence, the map $C_kF$ cannot be surjective either (its image also has measure zero). Thus, there exists a tuple $(x_1,...,x_k)\in N^k$ with pairwise distinct components such that the unordered tuple $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ does not belong to the image of $C_kF$. In other words, no matter what $a\in A$ and $y_1,..,y_k\in M$ you take,
$$
f_a(\{y_1,...,y_k\})\ne \{x_1,...,x_k\}. 
$$
Hence, we take $B=  \{x_1,...,x_k\}$ as our finite subset of $N$. qed
Lastly, I note that the configuration spaces $C_k(X)$ (and their analogues consisting of unordered $k$-tuples of distinct points in $X$) and induced maps $C_kf$ are a standard tool in the manifold topology.
